# What does "Edit removed during grace period" mean?

Tags: support, editing, user-accounts

I found this phrase on [one of the edits](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/301303/revisions) that I made today.

What does "Edit removed during grace period" mean? Does it mean that the OP is on *kind of* suspension and (s)he is not allowed to edit?

I have seen it several times, but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first five minutes after an edit, further edits get wrapped up into it, rather than making more entries in the post history. If you return the post to exactly how it was before you started editing it, that's the message that is displayed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand it now.